# FindResourceW() returns error code 127

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

Okay... so I am using Visual Studio 2010 making a win32 game... thingy. I am using a third party library that handles the graphics. It reads in a png file, creates the window, displays everything, and generally does a bunch of convenient low-level things that no one wants to deal with themselves.

Well, like any aspiring OCD programmer, I am trying to embed the png inside the executable because I don't like it to just be hangin' out in the directory for everyone to see. So, I got the source code, and started modifying it to, instead of load the png from a file, load it from a resource. I added the following code:

```
    HRSRC   hRsrc = FindResourceW(NULL, recName, recType);
    if (GetLastError() != 0)
    {
        char b[100];
        leave("Couldn't find resource", itoa(GetLastError(), b, 10));
    }
    HGLOBAL hGlob1 = LoadResource(NULL, hRsrc);
    int size = SizeofResource(NULL, hRsrc);
    HGLOBAL hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, size);
    LPVOID  resPtr = LockResource(hGlob1);
    LPSTREAM pStream;
    memcpy(hGlobal, resPtr, size);
    FreeResource(hGlob1);
    CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hGlobal, true, &pStream);
    buffer.resize((size_t)size);
    pStream->Read(&buffer[0], size, NULL);
    return;
```

`recName` is the resource's name. `recType` is the resource's type (these are both passed in as parameters). `leave` is a custom function that displays a popup message. `buffer` is the vector into which the png contents are read.

This library is compiled out into a statically linked library that my own code uses. So, my code does the actual embedding of the resources. Now, the thing is, this works, but only on a select few computers. I am able to run it, as is precisely one of my friends. On anyone else's computer, `GetLastError()` returns a 127, and as a result, the program craps out. According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx), error 127 is `The specified procedure could not be found.` ...whatever that means.

I have other embedded files in my executable, including mp3s and dlls, all made the same way, and they work fine (and, again, this png even works fine on my own computer), so I know it's not an issue of embedding things; I think I've pretty much got that down.

So then... what is error code 127 trying to tell me? Do my users' computers not know how to run function FindResourceW? If so, that makes absolutely no sense, because my code uses that function in other places, for loading the mp3s, and that works as well (and in fact, has worked, before I started trying to embed the png). Basically, I have never seen this kind of problem before, and I am stumped. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly using [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`FindResourceW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The documentation for `FindResourceW` (linked above) clearly says that `FindResourceW` returns a module handle (`HRSR`), and that you should check `GetLastError` **if it returns NULL** (emphasis added).

> Return value
>
> Type: HRSRC
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the specified resource's information block. To obtain a handle to the resource, pass this handle to the LoadResource function.
>
> **If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.**

From the documentation on `GetLastError` (again, linked above, and again **emphasis mine**:

> Return value
>
> The return value is the calling thread's last-error code.
>
> The Return Value section of the documentation for each function that sets the last-error code notes the conditions under which the function sets the last-error code. **Most functions that set the thread's last-error code set it when they fail. However, some functions also set the last-error code when they succeed. If the function is not documented to set the last-error code, the value returned by this function is simply the most recent last-error code to have been set; some functions set the last-error code to 0 on success and others do not.**

This says that unless the function is documented to set the last error code when it succeeds, the error code should only be used to indicate status *if the function fails*. Your code makes the assumption that if `GetLastError` is other than 0 then `FindResourceW` failed, and that assumption is wrong. :-) Because of that failed assumption, your code (wrongly) enters the `if` block and calls `leave` when it shouldn't, which would logically mean that the code after the `if` block ends is never executed.

`FindResourceW` is clearly documented to only `SetLastError` if it fails and returns `NULL`. The error value you're assuming is from `FindResourceW` is from somewhere else in your code that's setting the error value (which your code is apparently not reading).

So this would be closer to correct use (not a C++ guy myself):

```
HRSRC   hRsrc = FindResourceW(NULL, recName, recType);
if (!hRsrc)
{
    char b[100];
    leave("Couldn't find resource", itoa(GetLastError(), b, 10));
}
```

Comment: Unbelievable... And so fast, too. So... on the 8th day, the lord said... Let there be stackoverflow. And it was good.

Comment: ...I don't get it then. Where is `GetLastError` pulling a 127 from? Is `FindResourceW` succeeding in loading the resource, but generating an error anyway? If so, why would it do that?

Comment: It's getting it from wherever an error happened previously and wasn't read. As I said, the docs clearly say you should use `GetLastError` *only if the function fails and returns NULL*. You won't know if `FindResourceW` failed or not until you see what it returned. It's not `FindResourceW` setting the error unless you see that `FindResourceW` is actually failing. Since you're improperly assuming it did and getting into your `leave()` function, you're actually causing the later code to not be called yourself.

Comment: See my edited answer. I've added some info on GetLastError and successful API calls that may help clarify what you're seeing.

Comment: Hrm.. All right, well then... I guess the next issue is why does my computer somehow bypass whatever code is setting the last error to 127? ...But I guess that's another story for another time!

Comment: It's your **code** that is bypassing that error code, not your computer. To find out where, you're going to need to look at other places you're using the WinAPI and either ignoring or incorrectly checking return values. We can't see all of your code, and you'll need to go through it yourself and figure out where the problem occurs and fix it.

Comment: ...How can it be the code if running the exact same code on different computers produces different results?

Comment: Welcome to programming. :-) If you don't properly write your code to deal with the result of API calls, you can get different behavior on different machines for a zillion reasons (different amounts of memory, different CPU or load on it while running, different video cards, different operating systems (XP vs Win7, for instance), different updates being installed. The documentation clearly (for the most part, anyway) describes successful return values from API calls, and how to know if they succeeded or not; if you don't properly check and just make assumptions....